# Desktop is briefly shown after waking from suspend/sleep

Tags: suspend, security, bug-reporting, privacy

I open or close my laptop lid to initiate a sleep/suspend or wake it. When waking the laptop, it flashes my desktop briefly before blanking the screen and then showing the login. This is a potential security/privacy issue. I'm not sure if it's a bug or if it's something that could be fixed with some setting changes.

In an attempt to understand the problem better, I tried entering `xflock4` into the terminal and it went straight to a blank screen (which I set, instead of a screensaver). When I moved the mouse, it went straight to the login screen without showing the desktop.

I am working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Xubuntu release), and all packages are up to date as of today (February 7, 2021). If there's any further information you need to help me narrow down the issue, just let me know.

Comment: This seems to be [a long-standing bug](https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/issues/1#note_13821) that has not yet been resolved. It might be better to [report the issue on Launchpad](https://docs.xubuntu.org/contributors/qa-bugs.html) so that the development team can get some eyes on the issue. In the meantime, it may be necessary to lock the screen *then* close the lid 

Comment: @Matigo Thank you! I didn't realize that it was a long-standing bug. I had done a bunch of searches for it, but nothing came up. Thank you for your advice about locking the screen first! I'll try that. :)